# Split comma separated string with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a query that pulls the content of a text separated by comma exactly as this:

```
INSERVICE JOB #: N19020200001 
SERVICE_CENTER:SBY,OH_CIRCUIT:MALTA8501,CREW:3675,URD_PRINT:STG-123/S1,FEEDER:PFB969,ISOLATED_1:SCC-1-B969,ISOLATED_2:UDTB969-5,RECONDUCTOR:Y,JACKETED_CABLE:N,CABLE_CART:N,LIVE_FRONT:N,BOOM:null,BACK_HOE:null,EASY_HAULING:null
```

Is there a way in SQL I can select/partition it to be in separate fields as below (it is always consistent as above):

[image]

Comment: You say *"in SQL"* - does this mean you don't want a PL/SQL solution?

Comment: If you are using Oracle (perhaps for other db products too, I only know Oracle), perhaps the simplest, most efficient and least error-prone method is to have the text saved in plain text files, and then load it with SQL Loader or similar (or use facilities in gui's such as SQL Developer). If a job is worth doing at all, then it is worth doing it right.

Comment: @mathguy - it'd be nice to think so, but there's a ton of StackOverflow questions to show that many people disagree ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom string parser function you can use ...

NOTE: For headers, you can replace them like REPLACE('HEADER','') and get values with commas...

You can check below code and use it in your db:

```
  FUNCTION STRING_PARSER(VAL VARCHAR2, POSITION VARCHAR2, DELIMITER VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_pos3 number;
    v_pos4 number;
  BEGIN

    /* Return 3rd occurrence of '_' */
    v_pos3 := INSTR(VAL, DELIMITER, 1, POSITION) + 1;

    /* Return 4rd occurrence of '_' */
    v_pos4 := INSTR(VAL, DELIMITER, 1, POSITION + 1);

    return SUBSTR(VAL, v_pos3, v_pos4 - v_pos3);

  END;
```

Usage :

```
select report_tools_pkg.string_parser(',1,2,3',2,',') from dual
```

Note: Add a ',' || columnname to your sql if you want to you use ,it as it is ...